# Is this the right idea of a static class' justification

Tags: java, static

As static classes are not tied to any instance, is the following a good example (from a philosophical POV) of using a static class:

A spare tire (for a road vehicle), as this is not tied to any car (which can be another - albeit instance - class).

Thanks

The language concerned is Java (though I am a .NET Developer, I was practising in Java).

Comment: You have one spare tire for every car in existence? Remind me never to live in your world.

Comment: `static class` is only meaningful if you're talking about an inner/nested class. If that's what you're thinking - just make `tire` an independent, top-level class. If not, what do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by static class? and Answer is no you should not have this as static inner class. I would not do that even in .net.

Comment: Pretty sure this question is talking about static *inner* classes. I can see why you'd be unaware of the term *inner*, because it's not part of the declaration syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's still a tire; a tire doesn't have to be associated with a car--it could be associated with a tire rack, or the shoulder of a road.

A "static class" is one not generally meant to be instantiated, for example, a bunch of related utility methods that act on other classes or have other side effects.

(In quotes because there's no such thing as a top-level static class, only inner classes.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a static class is more of a "not related by instance-relation" in java. It's a bit like a singleton, but a singleton has one instance while a So basically, your normal classes are like cars. A static class is like the Brooklyn Bridge. Even if you build another, it won't be the Brooklyn Bridge. It's globally unique by definition.

Note that static means a different thing with inner classes. An inner static class is basically like an adopted child. Lives under the same roof, but no genetic connection (or rather, no `ParentClass.this` instance).

Comment: Brooklyn Bridge would be an instance of Bridge.

Comment: It would. However, that's an architecture issue, and in a completely canonical sense, everything is an instance of some generic. In fact, a static class is an instance of itself, and has nothing but the instance (no prototype). I guess some theoretical abstractions are just abstract :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about static *inner* classes. As you implied in your question, a static inner class is behaviourly very similar to a top-level class.

It can be considered useful to use a static class for encapsulation - particularly when marked  `private` or `protected`, its internals would never be accessed by a calling class.

Furthermore, I normally use `public` static inner classes in situations where the class's use is only relevant in terms of the parent class, such as a [Parameter Object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) (and kind-of similar to the common practice of a nested `enum`).

HTH